# Bytes and base64 formatting (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, base64, http.client, freshbooks-api

My scripting skills are very basic. I'm trying to adapt a Python 2 snippet I found on here to Python 3.

I'm having difficulty formatting this line (I understand it needs a bytes-object but can't get it to work).

```
headers["Authorization"] = "Basic {0}".format(
        base64.b64encode("{0}:{1}".format('auth', 'login')))
```

Full snippet:

```
import base64, http.client

headers = {}
body = '/api/2.1/xml-in'
headers["Authorization"] = "Basic {0}".format(
        base64.b64encode("{0}:{1}".format('auth', 'login')))
headers["Content-type"] = "application/xml"

# the XML we ll send to Freshbooks
XML = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<request method="task.list">
    <page>1</page>
    <per_page>15</per_page>
</request>"""


# Enable the job
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('sample.freshbooks.com')
conn.request('POST', body, None, headers)
resp = conn.getresponse()
print(resp.status)
conn.send(XML)

print(resp.read())
conn.close()
```

I've tried the following but then get an error about formatting the str:

```
headers["Authorization"] = "Basic {0}".format(
        base64.b64encode("%b:%b" % b'auth', b'login'))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a mouthful but the following works:

headers["Authorization"] = "Basic {0}".format(base64.b64encode(("{0}:{1}".format('string', 'string').encode('utf-8'))).decode())